# Full hard disc when properties show only 100GB used

Tags: hard-drive

I have laptop with 2 HDD, first is 125GB and second is 1 TB. Operating system windows 10 on hdd1. The problem is HDD2 and it is very confusing. It is running out of space but I didn't put 1TB on it. When I select all and go on properties I'm getting 100GB used that is far from 1TB. Anyone had similar problem? Please Advice

EDIT: OS is Windows 10.[image]

Comment: Try in Disk Management to resize disk tera to the maximum size that shows up.

Comment: Instead of select all -> properties.  Go up one level, right click on the drive -> properties.  If there are files you dont have access to (without taking ownership) like "WindowsApps" (where MS hides store bought games) these folders will report as ZERO.  What do the drive properties show you?

Answer (score 0):

What operating system? In Windows, open [diskmgmt.msc](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080), in Ubuntu, open
[gnome-disk-utility](https://linuxhint.com/gnome_disk_utility/), or for many OS's, install and use [GParted](https://gparted.org/), to *look* at how the 1 TB drive is partitioned and how it's being used.

If you cloned the 125 GB to the 1 TB drive, you might have created a partition using just 125 GB of the space, with the rest being left unassigned or in another partition. After you learn how the 1 TB drive is being used, you can decide what to do with any additional space, such as merging it into the existing partition or creating an additional "drive" (an additional drive letter).

Comment: I have edited the question. Seems like the size is ok in diskmgmt

Comment: When you right-click on each drive and select *Properties*, what is shown for used and free space?

Comment: used is almost the whole disk, free is 420 MB :(

Comment: Then it appears the 1 TB disk *is* full. Perhaps hidden files, perhaps backup files...

Comment: sql server had some dump files that filled my hard disk. I don't know why it didn't show them on properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: SQL Server had some dump files that filled my hard disk. I don't know why it didn't show them on properties.